# Read from html and write to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

I want read html and write few columns from it into an Excel table.I am currently using a macro to do it, but need it in VBScript.

I want to count the number of fail occurrences for compliance check and oracle table and write it into an Excel doc.

[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoSEB.jpg) of sample html and desired Excel file result.

[image: Sample html and desired excel output]

Answer (score 3):

Excel can be controlled from VBScript like this:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
```

The HTML file could be parsed into a DOM document:

```
Set doc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
doc.async = True
doc.load "C:\path\to\your.html"
```

Use an [XPath](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) expression to select al `<td>` elements:

```
Set td = doc.selectNodes("//tr/td")
```

At this point `td` contains a collection of all `<td>` elements in the document. You can process them like this:

```
numrows = doc.selectNodes("//tr").Length
numcols = td.Length / numrows

row = 0
For i = 0 To td.Length - 1 Step numcols
  If td(i).Text = "Fail" Then
    row = row + 1
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 1).Value = CDate(Split(td(i+2).Text)(0))
    If InStr(td(i+1).Text, "compliance") > 0 Then
      wb.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 2).Value = 1
    ElseIf InStr(td(i+1).Text, "Oracletable") > 0 Then
      wb.Sheets(1).Cells(row, 3).Value = 1
    End If
  End If
Next
```

The above will create a table like this:

```
2/9/2012    1    
2/9/2012         1
2/9/2012         1
.
.
.
```

You can then use Excel's [`Consolidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839594.aspx) method to consolidate the data:

```
Const xlSum = -4157

wb.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Consolidate _
  Array(wb.Sheets(1).Name & "!R1C1:R" & row & "C3"), xlSum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any [dom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) library to read in the html and the [OpenXML sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837.aspx) to write out to Excel (2007 format - xlsx). Does that answer your question or do you have something specific you are struggling with?

---

EDIT

Sorry, I thought for some reason you were talking about doing it in VB.Net, now I realize you are already in Excel. So I'm not clear on what you are asking - how to open the html file? how to calculate or store the values?

Perhaps post the script you have so far and be specific on what is not working.